# Layered Navigation display inline (horizontal)

Tags: css, magento, layered-navigation

in my magento i'd like to change layered navigation from this:

```
Filter By
Category
Computer (10)
Hard Disk (20)
Monitor (50)
```

to this:

```
Computer(10) Hard Disk (20) Monitor (50)
```

I'm trying to change in css from block to inline but it doesn't work.

How i can solve?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the css for your menu to the question

Comment: I found the right line in my css and it's work fine now.. (after about 5 hours)